# I am not able to start my application on real device using appium .Want to start CAlculator

Tags: java, selenium, android-studio, webdriver, appium

Error stack :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
>   remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
>   error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command. Original error: JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set
>   JAVA_HOME. Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358',
>   time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'WSDEL48240', ip:
>   '10.77.166.204', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '12.0.1' Driver info: driver.version:
>   AppiumDriver remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side
>   error occurred while processing the command. Original error: JAVA_HOME
>   is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME.
>       at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\ssolan01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>       at asyncHandler (C:\Users\ssolan01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: The error message shows the original error: Original error: JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

Do only one thing, uninstall appium server from **path:\Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features** and with **cmd npm unintsall -g appium**

After that install appium from here : 
https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.15.0-1

After that run following command :
npm install -g appium

It will work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I would recommend using the .exe installation only

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA_HOME is not set up in your system. JAVA_HOME is a system environment variable which represent JDK installation directory. When you install JDK in your machine (windows, Linux or unix) it creates a home directory and puts all its binary (bin), library(lib) and other.
So by following the below resource JAVA_HOME.

```
https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10
```

Please make your you copy correct path.

Comment: Hi .. If my JAVA_HOME path is not set , then how I am able to work on selenium and other java projects ?

Comment: If you're using java for your selenium projects. Then you must have to set JAVA_HOME path. Without that your IDE doesn't identify where your Java folder is actually. So you must have to set the path.